# MongoDB, Mongoose results from one Find to search another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I know this goes against the design of MongoDB and its No-SQL model but I'm trying to lookup Documents in one collection then use the ID field from the results to lookup corresponding records in another collection. Effectively trying to emulate a join.

```
//query is irrelevant to question
var results = collectionOne.find(query).limit(limit);

var a = [];

results.forEach(function(r)
{
    var aquery = { id : {$eq : r.id}};
    collectionTwo.find(aquery).limit(limit).exec(function, b)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            res.render('error',
            {
                status :  500
            });
        }
        else
        {
            a.push(b);
        }
   });
});
res.jsonp(a);
```

Comment: you can use aggregation with $lookup to execute this server side

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whilst there are new features in MongoDB such as [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), which does a "sort of join", your specific operation does not need this. All you are doing here is returning results from another collection based on where the `_id` value was mached from the previous one.

For this, the best option is to issue **one** more query on the other collection using [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

```
// Mongoose turns a cursor to an array by default in the callback method
collectionOne.find(query,{ "_id": 1}).limit(limit).exec(function(err,results) {

    // Just get array of _id values
    var ids = results.map(function(el) { return el._id } );

    // Not sure if you really mean both collections have the same primary key
    // I'm presuming two different fields being "id" as opposed to "_id"
    collectionTwo.find({ "id": { "$in": ids } },function(err,items) {
       // matching results are here
    })

})
```

That's it.

All you do is return your first query results of `_id` values as a "list" of just that, then supply that argument to `$in` on the related field in the target collection

If you really wanted a "join" and have MongoDB 3.2 available, then you can use `$lookup` like this

```
collectionOne.aggregate([
    { "$match": query },
    { "$limit": limit },
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "collectionTwo",
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "id",
        "as": "twoItems"
    }}
])
```

That's an actual "joined" result, and though you could *possibly* use it to just return the matched results from `collectionTwo`, then I personally would not. It is a costly excercise even on the server, and the further filtering an manipulation required to actually return that format would end up costing even more.

You also might read about `.populate()` in mongoose, which is actually the "reverse" of this type of query. Instead it's process is to store an array ( or regular field, but array in this case ) of `ObjectId` values pointing to the primary key of objects in the related collection. So if there were "many" values for `collectionTwo`, then these would be stored in an array within `collectionOne` documents.

Again, this is a "join emulation" and not a real join. The result would be similar to the `$lookup`, and again is not really "just" the results from `collectionTwo`, but the "joined" version, that you would similarly need to filter.

All that really happens with `.populate()` is that it runs an `$in` query anyway. So even after all the work of storing child references in a parent ( an IMHO, in most cases if you can do that then you may as well just embed the data instead ) the actual interaction with the database remains unchanged in that it still does an `$in` query.

Comment: @user3424480 Not to sure what you think you mean there. If you mean that when a "source" uses `ObjectId` then the "target" must as well, then of course it does. That remains true for any BSON type.